# Strange error on stringed Linq calls

Tags: iterator, sum, ienumerable

I inherited this code that takes an IEnumerable and performs a series of Selects on it and then attempts to call Sum on the remaining records after the Selects are performed. The code reads as:

```
var totalrecs = records.Select(row => new RowInfo(RowID = row.RowID, SomeData = row.SomeData})
.Select(ri => new {RowInfo = ri, XMLData = GetXMLFileForRecord(ri)})
.Select(data => ParseAndUpdateRecords(data.RowInfo, data.XmlData))
.Sum();
```

where 'records' is an IEnumerable.

The error is for attempting to convert a decimal to a long and from the StackTrace seems to be occurring when calling Sum on the Iterator that results from the three Select calls.

The stack trace is:

```
Exception:Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'long'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at RecordCapture.Controller.<CaptureAndUpdateRecords>b__10(Object row)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable`1 source)
at RecordCapture.Controller.CaptureAndUpdateRecords()
at RecordCapture.Controller.<Start>b__1() 
StackTrace:   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at RosterCapture.Controller.<CaptureAndUpdateRosters>b__10(Object row)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable`1 source)
at RecordCapture.Controller.CaptureAndUpdateRecords()
at RecordCapture.Controller.<Start>b__1()
```

The Selects return an Iterator and there does not seem to be any way to get an accurate count of what the result of the Selects is.

Interestingly, if records is empty, calling Sum simply returns a zero and does not throw an error.

Comment: If you wanted the count you could have called .Count() instead of .Sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The Stack Trace was misleading.

The issue was in building up the RowInfo object in my code... the RowID was a long and the variable that the property was setting it's value to was a decimal.

I believe the error occurred in the Sum call because of lazy loading where the setting of the attributes was not done until that call was made and the data was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Sum integers or decimals?  Use the Generic type appropriate, and cast the result if necessary.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx for the overload list.

Comment: In the example I gave, Sum is called on an Iterator. The link you provided is doing it on a simple List of ints. I don't see how that helps. Can you give a solid example of how you would do it in the code I provided?

Comment: Sum indicates you are taking an Enumerable of some type of numeric value, and adding them together. You cannot Sum an 'Iterator', so to speak.  What is the Type of the Values you are trying to Sum?  If the answer is not a numeric type, then you are not doing with your code what you think you are doing.